# alternative to MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for Android 10

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-api-levels

I would like my flutter app to have write-access to the whole external storage (/sdcard/Android in particular) and I found the documentation of [ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) which seems like exactly what I would need, as it also grants access outside of the apps data and obb folder.
Unfortunately this action has just been implemented in API level 30 which is not yet usable for me.
I am aware of

```
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

which unfortunately also just gives me access to the apps folder.
In the documentation they wrote that this permission level is used by antiviruses.
There must be a way to archive the same in API 29.
I am grateful for any hints!

Comment: You do realize that `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission [can't currently be used in the Google Play Store](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play). Without knowing why you want "full access" you should read Commonware's posts on [Internal](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [External](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [Removable](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) storage.

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" `unfortunately also just gives me access to the apps folder.` No. That flag on an Android 10 device gives access to the whole of external storage. Further you did not mention Android version of used devices.

Comment: What you mention in the subject of your post does not appear in the post itself. Not nice.

Answer (score 0):

[ext_storage plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage) grants access to folders outside the app folder on Android. No need to modify the Android app's manifest.